# Kafka Producer Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I tried to implement a simple producer consumer example with kafka and I achieved with the following properties:

```
Properties configProperties = new Properties();
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:" + portNumber);
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    // Belirtilen property ayarlarına sahip kafka producer oluşturulur
    org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer producer = new KafkaProducer(configProperties);
```

However when I try the exact same configs, and everything else the same, in another project which is a plugin for a data visualization software, I got this error:

```
.... // Here there is some other stuff but I thing the important one is the below one
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer
at App.MyControlPanel.<init>(MyControlPanel.java:130)
at App.CytoVisProject.<init>(CytoVisProject.java:29)
... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 98 more
```

In the first one that I said it worked, I was using "mvn clean compile assembly:single", but in the second one I created a jar file for the whole project. Because the visualization software wants a jar file to install the plugin. Since every thing is same (At least I could not find any difference, I used same code) I guess the problem is about the way build the project. What happened here? What is the difference between "mvn clean compile assembly:single" and building a jar file in IntelliJ? Why I got this error and how to fix this? Thanks a lot for help!

---

As I said in the last comment of the first answer, I have a plugin which has manifest and transform as goal. Here:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.springsource.bundlor</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.bundlor.maven</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputManifest>C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\archetype2tmp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</outputManifest>
                <failOnWarnings>false</failOnWarnings>
                <removeNullHeaders>true</removeNullHeaders>
                <manifestHeaders><![CDATA[Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: CytoVisProject
Bundle-SymbolicName: CytoVisProject
Spring-DM-Version: ${pom.version}
]]></manifestHeaders>
            </configuration>
            <!-- generate the manifest automatically during packaging -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                        <goal>transform</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

If I use a shade plugin like below:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

It does not works, because I need to use manifest and transform as goals in my plugin. How can I add kafka classes to the jar file that IntelliJ creates to solve this problem (I am not sure if this can solve or not)?

Comment: Did you include the dependencies in the JAR?

Comment: @jrtapsell I added this jar file "kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar" from the Libraries tab under the project structure. And it is exist in pom.xml. Is it enough?

Comment: It needs to be in the classpath (classpath issues are common in plugins), if the classes are in the JAR then they will be found, otherwise, the plugin needs to add the dependency JAR manually.

Comment: @jrtapsell Yes, Producer and consumer class is in the jar file that IntelliJ creates. I do not know the classpath thing, how can I solve this? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You need to provide the `kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar` file in your plugin, at the moment it is available at compile time, so no compile errors, then disappears at runtime, hence your error

Comment: First things first
>which is a plugin for a data visualization software
Is this an intelij plugin?
Irrespective of what this plugin is how will this be deployed?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an easier solution. I have changed

```
kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

to this

```
kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
```

And afterwards my code run, also as part of a pre-compiled plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

## What the problem is

At compile time `kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar` is available, so the code compiles successfully, but at runtime it is missing, hence the error you get.

## How to fix it

You have 2 options:

- Include the kafka JAR inside your JAR
- Add the kafka JAR to your plugin's classpath

Comment: I added this jar file to the resources file in the maven project, now when I buid and create a jar file for the plugin, kafka-clients jar appears in plugin's jar file. But again I got the same error.

Comment: You need to include the classes in the JAR, not the whole JAR, [this](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/) should help

Comment: I did exact same steps, but It did not worked again. Is there any way to add kafka jar to classpath?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Kafka classes are mixed in to your JAR file, rather than staying in their own one

Comment: No they are not mixed. @jrtapsell

Comment: Ah, the default class loader won't read from sub-jars, if you follow the fat jar instructions you should get a mixed jar which should work

Comment: Hello again, In a shade plugin pom.xml (maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) like this, as I can see we need to specify shade as goal. But in my plugin I need to add manifest and transform as goal. So if I try to add 2 plugin, one for shade and one for manifest and transform, I got this error: "Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.springsource.bundlor:com.springsource.bundlor.maven:1.0.0.M2 " These are the groupId and artifactId of the plugin which has manifest and  transform as goals and I can not add shade goal to mine because it does not recognize. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you don't have a dependency for kafka-clients marked with provided scope.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).